# Java program to detect the Java class File Format magic number, in a given file

Tags: java, file-structure

**Description:**

I wrote a Java program that checks whether the content of the given file begins with the Java class File Format magic number `0xCAFEBABE`, in big-endian byte order.

It prints a success message if:

- The first 4 bytes match the magic number

It prints an error message if:

- The file doesn't exist or cannot be read
- The file contains less than 4 bytes
- The first 4 bytes don't match the magic number

It prints a usage message if:

- A file is not given as input

**Code:**

```
import java.io.*;

public class Magic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Magic <FILE>");
            return;
        }

        try {
            if (isMagicPresent(args[0])) {
                System.out.println(String.format("'%s' contains the magic number.", args[0]));
            } else {
                System.out.println(String.format("'%s' doesn't contain the magic number.", args[0]));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static boolean isMagicPresent(String file) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
            int readCount = instream.read(bytes);

            if (readCount == 4) {
                return Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[0]) == 0xCA &&
                        Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[1]) == 0xFE &&
                        Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[2]) == 0xBA &&
                        Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[3]) == 0xBE;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Question:**

How can I improve the above code in terms of:

- Readability
- Performance
- Boundary case and error handling

Answer (score 3):

### Interface

For clarity, `isMagicPresent()` should accept a `java.io.File` (or `java.nio.file.Path`) to emphasize that the argument is a path and not the contents of a file.

The default constructor should be suppressed.

### Implementation

To read a big-endian `int`, use [`DataInputStream.readInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29).  Then you can compare the magic number to `0xCAFEBABE` rather than four bytes.

### Driver

I recommend returning a non-zero exit code to indicate that an error has occurred.

When no argument is given, the error message should go to `System.err`.  (If you supported a `-h` or `--help` option, then its output should go to `System.out`, because that *would* be the requested output.)

Instead of `System.out.println(String.format(…))`, you should just call `System.out.format(…)`.  Here, I've chosen to combine both cases into one print statement, but you don't have to.

### Suggested implementation

```
import java.io.*;

public class Magic {
    private Magic() {}

    public static boolean isMagicPresent(File f) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(f);
             DataInputStream dataInStream = new DataInputStream(inStream)) {
            return dataInStream.readInt() == 0xCAFEBABE;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Magic <FILE>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        File f = new File(args[0]);
        try {
            System.out.format(
                "'%s' %s the magic number.%n",
                f,
                isMagicPresent(f) ? "contains" : "doesn't contain"
            );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me overall it was very easy to read and follow.

Nitpicking:

- Since you want to accept a single input, you can actually check for `if (args.length == 1)`
- You are already chaining the conditionals so why not the following?

```
private static boolean isMagicPresent(String file) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        return is.read(bytes) == 4 &&
                Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[0]) == 0xCA &&
                Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[1]) == 0xFE &&
                Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[2]) == 0xBA &&
                Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[3]) == 0xBE;
    }
}
```

- You can present the example usage within quotes as in `'filename.ext'` since whitespaces are allowed in most operating systems and I may try running your program as in `java Magic Mag ic.class` which would return `Mag (No such file or directory)` but running with `java Magic 'Mag ic.class'` returns `'Mag ic.class' contains the magic number.` when I actually have this file..
- `isMagicPresent` can accept an `InputStream` instead of a file path which would make testing the method easier and de-coupling it from a file.

```
private static boolean isMagicPresent(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    return is.read(bytes) == 4 &&
            Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[0]) == 0xCA &&
            Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[1]) == 0xFE &&
            Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[2]) == 0xBA &&
            Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[3]) == 0xBE;
}
```

Keep up the good work.